# how to start the service in target server using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to run the following ansible playbook to start the "nexus" service on remote server at path  "nexux/bin" it gets failed :

```
  - hosts: nexus
    become: yes
    become_user: nexus
    become_method: sudo
    tasks:
      - name: changing dir and starting nexus service
        shell:
          chdir: nexux/bin
          executable: ./nexus start
```

Can someone troubleshoot here to deduce the root cause ?

Comment: And what is the output of your command, i.e. the error message? Have you tried it to run with `-vvv`?

Comment: "chdir: nexux/bin" instead of "chdir: nexus/bin" is a typo here right?

Answer (score 0):

As the ansible output very clearly told you, in that syntax you did not provide a **command**. The `executable:` is designed to be the **shell** executable, not the "run this thing" argument. It is very clear [in the examples section of the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/shell_module.html#examples)

```
- shell: cd /opt/nexus/bin && ./nexus start
```

If you want to use the `chdir:` option, you must put it under a sibling yaml key to the `shell:`, like so:

```
- shell: echo hello world
  args:
    chdir: /opt/nexus/bin
    # I'm omitting the "executable:" key here, because you for sure
    # do not want to do that, but if you did, then fine, put it here
```

Having said all of that, as the docs *also* indicate, what you really want is to use `command:` because you are not making use of any special *shell* characters (redirects, pipes, `&&` phrases, etc), so:

```
- command: ./nexus start
  args:
    chdir: /opt/nexus/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use the shell module, i also recommend to run with nohup and send the output to a file

```
- shell: |
  cd /opt/nexus/bin
  nohup ./nexus start > /tmp/nexus.log 2>&1 &
```